# Batch process automatic filling of two columns

Tags: qgis, batch

I would like to automatically fill two columns in my batch process. Column 3 is to be numbered consecutively with "fid_". Column 5 is to be numbered consecutively with "fid_Mi_". In total there are several hundred individual processes.

Unfortunately, I cannot get both columns to be numbered consecutively in the same way.
Does anyone have a solution for me or is there already a post about this?
[image]